# Deploying/hosting Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, intellij-idea

I have recently finished a simple spring boot application using the INTELLIJ IDE. The applications runs locally as a spring application as well as in Tomcat.

For my next step I would like to be able to host the application online but every attempt i've made seems to fail it doesn't even run on Xampp's Tomcat.

Heres my hierachy:

- src
- ----java
- ---------com.jcode
- ---------------TestController.java
- ---------------Application.java
- ----resources
- ---------application.properties

application.properties:

```xml
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3306/db_digitrainer
spring.datasource.username=test
spring.datasource.password=test

server.context-path=/digitrainer

management.context-path=/manage
```

Application.java:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

I have been unable to find any clear information on how to do this so I would love to know if I am doing something wrong and also if spring boot is the approach for developing a rest API.

Answer (score 1):

I find deploying at Pivotal Could Foundry seamless. For that, this [guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/sts-cloud-foundry-deployment/) works well when using STS. When using some other IDE, or for the elaborated steps, [this blog post](http://www.naturalprogrammer.com/pivotal-cloud-foundry-spring-boot-web-applications/) could be useful. Yes, I find Spring Boot quite good for developing a REST API, and am almost nearing the end of developing the first version of [an open source project](https://github.com/naturalprogrammer/spring-lemon) for that purpose.

Answer (score 0):

It seems my problem was a typical beginner issue. When building my project I did end up with two WAR files in my build directory which I tried to deploy. Because these WAR files were not packaged yet they obviously didn't work.

In the end all I had forgotten to do was open cmd, navigate to my project directory and use maven's "mvn package" command. After that everything worked.